# Force MATLAB to make only commas as column separators

Tags: matlab

The other day I discovered the following bug in a couple of places in my MATLAB code

I wanted to enter the column vector in my MATLAB script

```
[a-b,
 c-d
 e-f]
```

where a,b,c,d,e,f are long expressions in some variables.

and I entered it in as

```
 [ a -b ;
   c -d ;
   e -f]
```

Now MATLAB interprets the second matrix as a 3x2 matrix instead of a column vector. 
Is there a way/command/function to force MATLAB to use only the comma and NOT any white space characters as a column separator for matrices ?

Comment: That's not actually a bug - it's expected behaviour. I agree with you that it's not nice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a piece of code in which you only want to have column vectors and no matrix, there is a fairly quick solution:

replace `{space}+` by `+`

replace `{space}-` by `-`

It is quite safe to do and unless you have complicated expressions in your vector it should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any way to force matlab to not treat white space this way, since it is interpretive language, and doing so may affect some built-in functions/third-party code.
However, you can use parentheses to group data - i.e. (a -b) will still be a single element of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Well your second matrix does look like it's intended as a 3x2. However, if you do it like this it will be a column vector again:

```
[a - b;
 c - d;
 e - f]
```

which to me is a reasonable intuitive distinction between `a` minus `b` and `a`, negative `b`.

You can also use brackets as Ilya suggested.